# Overriding the EmailMessage class of Django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I am working on an existing Project which uses Django 1.7 
We are integrating our Email services with Amazon Ses. This has raised a problem that we are not able to monitor which email are sent successfully and which one's have failed. So I am thinking of logging the errors where email sending has failed.
Currently EmailMessage class of django.core.mail is being used to send the emails and adding the code for logger everywhere will be a dirty solution. So I am thinking of overriding the EmailMessage class and Using my Custom class to send emails and add the logic for logging there.
Here's the code for that

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

class EmailMessaging(EmailMessage):

    def send(self):
        result = super(EmailMessaging, self).send()
        if(result):
            print 'success'
            #do nothing successful
        else:
            print 'fail' 
            #failed:- add event to logger | Db | Sentry
```

When I try to consume myClass for sending the email it throws an error:-

```
from email_message import EmailMessaging
message = EmailMessaging("this is the subject", "this is the body”, "sender@abc.com", ["myemailaddress@abc.com”])
```

> SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

However, if I use the EmailMessage class it is working fine. I am not able to understand why is this happening.
From what I have read, I think that by overriding the EmailMessage class I am missing out on some Default Config setting which is resulting in the error. Is it the case?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return a result like in [parent class method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L339)

```
class EmailMessaging(EmailMessage):

    def send(self):
        result = super(EmailMessaging, self).send()
        if(result):
            print 'success'
            #do nothing successful
        else:
            print 'fail' 
            #failed:- add event to logger | Db | Sentry
        return result
```